# javascript var into onClick in html

Tags: javascript, json

I have a var I need to be sent as a JSON string for AS3. It has to be sent as printed out in the link. How can I get my var to be in the onClick of an html as seen below?

```
   <script>
    var NeedMyVarHere = {
    One:"This is var one!",
    Two:"This is JSON Object 2"
                };
      NeedMyVarHere = JSON.stringify(NeedMyVarHere);
     </script>


 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AirBridge.evoke('myCustomFunction(NeedMyVarHere)')" return false;>Testing!</a>
```

UPDATE to clarify.

The AS requires a "string be sent" but you can declare a custom function in a string. I didn't write the class. I just need a JSON object written in String format inside my onClick. Like this:

```
onClick="AirBridge.evoke('myCustomFunction({One:"This is var one!",Two:"This is var Two"})"
```

But I am hoping to use a single var to print it out like...

```
onClick="AirBridge.evoke('myCustomFunction(NeedMyVarHere)"
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Try not to use inline event handlers.

Comment: return it from the function??  That seems an overly simple answer, so maybe I don't understand the question properly..

Comment: @Hacketo it is global....

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in details here https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE/issues/48 but yet, here's a copy:

in your JS, create a button or link to call a JS function

```
<button type="button" onClick="sendComplexDataToAir()">Send Complex Data To Air</button>
```

in your js code, create your Json and send it back to Air like this:

```
function sendComplexDataToAir()
{
    var myJSONObject = 
    {
        "someData": 
        [
            {"var1": "value 1"},
            {"var2": "value 2"},
            {"var3": "value 3"},
            {"var3": "As long as you have a valid Json in JS, you can have it received on the Air side with no problem!"}
        ]
    };

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify  
    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject);

    // http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp
    var encodedStr = encodeURIComponent(jsonStr);

    // and finally send it to flash
    AirBridge.evoke('parseJson('+ encodedStr +')');
}
```

then, receive it on the Air side like this

```
private function onReceivedMassage(e:RichWebViewEvent):void
{
    DynamicFunc.run(this, e.param);
}

public function parseJson($str:String):void
{
    trace(decodeURIComponent($str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `unobtrusive` JavaScript using `addEventListener`. But for this solution, I would say:

```
onclick="AirBridge.evoke('myCustomFunction(NeedMyVarHere)')" return false;
//---------------------------------------------------------^ " prematurely closed.
```

Change to:

```
onclick="AirBridge.evoke('myCustomFunction(' + NeedMyVarHere.One + ')'); return false;"
```

Or:

```
onclick="AirBridge.evoke('myCustomFunction(NeedMyVarHere)'); return false;"
```

Comment: Giving a reason for downvote will be brilliant. `:)`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I asked a question and I get downvotes and nobody explains why.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not  do something like illustrated below?

```
<script>
    var NeedMyVarHere = {
        One:"This is var one!",
        Two:"This is JSON Object 2"
    };
    NeedMyVarHere = JSON.stringify(NeedMyVarHere);
    function onClickFunction() {
        Airbridge.evoke(myCustomFunction(NeedMyVarHere));
    }
 </script>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="onClickFunction()">Testing!</a>
```

This way the onClick-function doesn't need to accept an argument but can call the parameterless function 'onClickFunction' which then calls the function (with the argument) you wanted to call in the first place.

Comment: Not me, but when I see your code: `onclick="onClickFunction" return false;` is totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. Fixed it. This code is tested and works.:-) 
I am not entirely sure whether it solves Papa's problem though.

Comment: OP also needs it passes as a string, you are not doing that.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is it is not passing the reference to the variable since it is just a hardcoded string. Since it needs to be a string, you are better off using addEventListener and build the string instead of an inline event.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="myLink">xxxx</a>
```

and the script

```
document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    AirBridge.evoke("myCustomFunction('" + JSON.stringify(NeedMyVarHere) + "')");
    return false;   // or e.preventDefault();
});
```

Make sure this line runs after the element is added to the page (document ready, onload, or just in the body after the element.)